# Best way to wait for an asychronous network task within AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, vimeo-api

I'm working through the Vimeo API in my android app to pull the link for a particular vimeo video from my Vimeo Pro account and then download this video through an AsyncTask.  The read/write of the file is fine, but I'm having trouble pulling the link and passing it to that method.

The code is as follows:

```
 class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    ...
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(final String... args) {
        // args[1]/name is the output file name
        String name = args[1];
        ...
        // pos is the position within the vimeo channel's array
        final int pos = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);

        //Here is the main code, args[2] is the channel id for 
        //the specific vimeo channel that the code 
        //needs to pull the video files from.
        VimeoClient.getInstance().fetchNetworkContent(args[2], new ModelCallback<VideoList>(VideoList.class) {
                @Override
                public void success(VideoList videoList) {

                   //If the video exists, get the video object, 
                   //and then get the video files related to that object from download[].
                    if (videoList != null && videoList.data != null && !videoList.data.isEmpty()) {
                        Video video = videoList.data.get(pos);
                        ArrayList<VideoFile> videoFiles = video.download;

                        // Get the video file, and then get it's link, store as string.
                        if(videoFiles != null && !videoFiles.isEmpty()) {
                            VideoFile videoFile = videoFiles.get(2); // you could sort these files by size, fps, width/height
                            String link = videoFile.getLink();

                            **link = [test direct link to mp4];
                            DownloadFile(link, args[1]);**
                        }
                    }
                }
                ...
            });

            **//String link = [test direct link to mp4];
            //DownloadFile(link, args[1]);**
        }
        ...
    }
```

The string variable and DownloadFile(String link, string outputName) lines towards the end of the code is my main problem. I printed out the link's from videoFile.getLink() and used that as a test link for the code. When I run string link = xxx, and DownloadFile outside of the vimeoClient.fetchNetworkContent (as commented out at the very end), the code works while when they are placed inside the fetchNetworkContent() method, it hits a NetworkOnMainThreadException.

The problem is that I need to retrieve the link before DownloadFile() runs. Is there a way for me to fix this within the fetchNetworkContent? Or is there a way for me to force the system to wait before the DownloadFile() that is commented out until the networkFetchContent is complete?

EDIT: So I updated my code based on cricket_007's answer of chaining AsyncTasks. Instead of creating a second AsyncTask though, I decided to just loop it through the same task with a logic system.

First running DownloadFileFromURL() basically asks, what information am I given?

If given a url, it will run DownloadFile(url, outputtedFileName).
If not, if it receives the keyword "vimeo", it uses the vimeoClient to find the link, which then runs DownloadFileFromURL(vimeoLinkURL, outputtedFileName) from within. I just used a logic tree, I suppose.

```
    class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    /**
     * Downloading file in background thread
     */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(final String... args) {
        final String name = args[1];

        // Check if this is already a url link ending in .mp4
        if(FilenameUtils.isExtension(args[0], "mp4")){
                DownloadFile(args[0], args[1]);
        } 

        //If not, is it a vimeo video? Check with keyword "vimeo" 
        else if (args[0].contains("vimeo")){
            final int pos = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
            VimeoClient.getInstance().fetchNetworkContent(args[2], new ModelCallback<VideoList>(VideoList.class) {
                @Override
                public void success(VideoList videoList) {
                    Log.d("VimeoClient", "Success in VimeoList Reading");

                    if (videoList != null && videoList.data != null && !videoList.data.isEmpty()) {

                        Video video = videoList.data.get(pos);
                        ArrayList<VideoFile> videoFiles = video.download;

                        if(videoFiles != null && !videoFiles.isEmpty()) {
                            VideoFile videoFile = videoFiles.get(2); // you could sort these files by size, fps, width/height

                            String link = videoFile.getLink();
                            new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(link, args[1], args[2], args[3]);
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(VimeoError error) {
                    Log.d("VimeoError", "Failure in VideoList Reading in VideoDownloader class");
                }
            });
            // return null so that the Toast is not created for completion 
            // since this ends in DownloadFile()
            return null;
        }
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String fileName) {
        if(fileName != null) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Completed download of " + fileName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I've marked his answer as correct, not because it was the final code, but I find it much more informative than the specific code that I used. My code really is specific to my particular solution in this use case, but his explanation was the real solution.

Comment: I think it's likely that `ModelCallBack#success()` is being called on the UI thread. I suggest that instead of wrapping the `fetchNetworkContent()` call in an `AsyncTask`, you call it directly on the UI thread (it should run in a separate thread anyway) and then create your `AsyncTask` in the `success()` method to call `DownloadFile()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't clear what the DownloadFile method is doing, but you might need a secondary AsyncTask for it.

Sidenote: I would hope that `VimeoClient.getInstance().fetchNetworkContent` would run in it's own thread anyway, so it shouldn't need an AsyncTask, but we'll pretend it doesn't.

Recommended approach to "wait" for an AsyncTask is to carefully chain the calls together. For example, if you give one AsyncTask the callback, then the `success` method gets ran. From within that `success`, you can start a new task that will call `DownloadFile` (probably give it the whole `ArrayList<VideoFile>` rather than just one link if you want to download all the links)

```
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    private ModelCallback<VideoList> callback;

    public DownloadFileFromURL(ModelCallback<VideoList> callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final String... args) {

        //Here is the main code, args[0] is the channel id for 
        //the specific vimeo channel that the code 
        //needs to pull the video files from.
        VimeoClient.getInstance().fetchNetworkContent(args[0], callback);

    }
    ...
}
```

Then, wherever you call that task, pass in the interface for the action you want to perform

```
// Need these values inside the callback - have to be final
final String arg1;
final int pos; 

// The callback that is hit from doInBackground()
ModelCallback<VideoList> callback = new ModelCallback<VideoList>(VideoList.class) {
    @Override
    public void success(VideoList videoList) {

       //If the video exists, get the video object, 
       //and then get the video files related to that object from download[].
        if (videoList != null && videoList.data != null && !videoList.data.isEmpty()) {
            Video video = videoList.data.get(pos);
            ArrayList<VideoFile> videoFiles = video.download;

            // Get the video file, and then get it's link, store as string.
            if(videoFiles != null && !videoFiles.isEmpty()) {
                VideoFile videoFile = videoFiles.get(2); // you could sort these files by size, fps, width/height
                String link = videoFile.getLink();

                // TODO: Might need to execute another AsyncTask
                DownloadFile(link, arg1);
            }
        }
    }
    ...
};

// pass the callback to the task 
new DownloadFileFromURL(callback).execute("channel_id");
```

Comment: I used your explaination as the basis for how I should solve the problem. As explained above in my edit, I decided to loop it through the same AsycTask. However, you mention that fetchNetworkContent should probably run in it's own thread. Which I think it does? It doesn't have to run in an AsyncTask if that's what you mean (still learning and I don't know much about threads). If this is so, would reworking this section of this code be "better"?

Comment: If it runs in the background on its own, then yeah, probably best not to have the AsyncTask. You can move the "successfully completed" message to the end of the callbacks success method

Comment: The fetch method will do it's work on a new thread - the success block is called on the thread you initiated the request from. You do not need to wrap it in an AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that you can try doing.

```
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> implements LinkReceivedListener{
...
LinkRecievedListener callbackListener;

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // The result is the returned String link value from doInbackground()
    DownloadFile(result, args[1]);
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(final String... args) {
    String name = args[1];
    final int pos = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);

    VimeoClient.getInstance().fetchNetworkContent(args[2], new ModelCallback<VideoList>(VideoList.class) {
            @Override
            public void success(VideoList videoList) {

               //If the video exists, get the video object, 
               //and then get the video files related to that object from download[].
                if (videoList != null && videoList.data != null && !videoList.data.isEmpty()) {
                    Video video = videoList.data.get(pos);
                    ArrayList<VideoFile> videoFiles = video.download;

                    // Get the video file, and then get it's link, store as string.
                    if(videoFiles != null && !videoFiles.isEmpty()) {
                        VideoFile videoFile = videoFiles.get(2); // you could sort these files by size, fps, width/height
                        String link = videoFile.getLink();
                        callbackListener.onSuccess(link);
                    }
                }
            }
            ...
        });
    }
    ...
}

public interface LinkRecievedListener {
    void onSuccess(String linkString);
}
```

Comment: This won't work... The success method is void, you can't return from it

Comment: I have edited my answer. It should point you to the right direction.